# Is there any place or way to store private key in google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, httprequest, api-key

I'm working on a small project using Google App Script now. What I need to do is make both GET and POST request to API. I'm working on a GET request for now and wrote the code below.

```
var myApiKey = "123456789"
const requestServer = (path, method, params = {}) => {
  if (method.toUpperCase() === "GET"){
    var url = "https://api.xyz.com/" + path + "apikey=" + myApiKey; 
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
  } else if (method.toUpperCase() === "POST"){

  }
}
```

I used fake url and apikey for asking this question.
My question is if there is a place or a way to store myApiKey in Google App Script, like .env file?
If so how should I store and make my key hidden...

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your goal, how about the following 3 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, how about using Properties Service? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) When the script is run, the value can be put and retrieved using Properties Service.

In this case, at first, it is required to input the value to Properties Service.

Sample script:

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

// Put value.
scriptProperties.setProperty("key", "value");

// Get value.
var value = scriptProperties.getProperty("key");
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, how about using the custom file properties? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties) This can be put and retrieve the value using Drive API.

In this case, at first, it is required to input the value to the custom file properties.

Sample script:

```
var fileId = ScriptApp.getScriptId();

// Put value.
Drive.Files.update({properties: [{key: "key", value: "value"}]}, fileId);

// Get value.
var savedKey = "key";
var obj = Drive.Files.get(fileId).properties.filter(({key}) => key == savedKey);
if (obj.length == 0) throw new Error("No property for the inputted key");
var value = obj[0].value;
```

#### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, how about using a temporal file? In this case, this can be used like `.env file`. At first, the value is put to the file (in this case, I think that the text file and Google Docs file can be used.). And, when the script is run, the value is retrieved from the file and use it in the script.

Sample script:

```
// Put value.
DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", "value");

// Get value.
var value = DriveApp.getFileById("###fileId###").getBlob().getDataAsString().trim();
```

#### References:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)
- [Add custom file properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties)

Comment: Thank you so much Tanaike! I was reading the first solution you gave me, but I cannot find the service/propertyService.gs in my Apps Script project... Could you tell me where is the file located?

Comment: @Yuuu Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about but I cannot find the service/propertyService.gs in my Apps Script project... Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? By the way, from your replying, I cannot understand about the pattern you are using. I apologize for this. Can I also ask you about this? From these information, I would like to confirm your current situation. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Tanaike! SInce you gave me three solutions, I chose pattern 1 to solve this problem (which is using Properties Service). Then I read the ref you gave me (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties). In the document, I saw I have to store data in service/propertyService.gs file, but I was not sure where the service folder and propertyService.gs file are. btw your English is perfect :)

Comment: @Yuuu Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I understood the page you are seeing. In that case, `service/propertyService.gs` is the sample filename. So when you test the script, please just copy and paste the script to your script editor. By this, you can use the script.

Comment: @Yuuu Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation from your replying. If my proposed answer was not useful for your situation, I apologize for it and I would like to modify it. So, can I ask you about your current situation?